# how to set 800 rows of values on x-axis and make the chart look readable?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am building a power bi report and I have a column that holds disease names(800 rows), I need to build a report which shows "patient flow by disease name and state", I am seeing 800 records on the x-axis which does not look good. is there any way I can make it look good?

I tried grouping the disease names but I am still seeing more than 400 rows which still not good:
[image]

Comment: Tried adjusting bar width?

Comment: You can go with the top 50 if that makes more sense..

Answer (score 1):

In general 800 categories would be too much data for a bar chart.

However, if I were in your shoes, I would group the disease names into Alphabetical groups. Then create a hierarchy with the alphabetical group on top and the disease names at the next level. Anyone who wants to look at a specific disease can drill down into the alphabetical group. Hope this helps.